# Avoid spurious space in print

Tags: python, printing

I did not expect this, but:

```
print "AAAA",
print "BBBB"
```

Will output:

```
AAAA BBBB
```

With an extra space in the middle. This is actually [documented](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print).

How can I avoid that supurious space? The documentation says:

```
In some cases it may be functional to write an empty string to standard output for this reason.
```

But I do not know how to do that.

Comment: "But I do not know how to do that." The documentation is not telling you how to avoid the problem you are asking about. The documentation is telling you how to make use of the behaviour you don't want, in other situations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three options:

- Don't use two print statements, but concatenate the values:

  ```
  print "AAAA" + "BBBB"
  ```
- Use `sys.stdout.write()` to write your statements directly, not using the `print` statement

  ```
  import sys

  sys.stdout.write("AAAA")
  sys.stdout.write("BBBB\n")
  ```
- Use the [forward-compatible new `print()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print):

  ```
  from __future__ import print_function

  print("AAAA", end='')
  print("BBBB")
  ```

Comment: Thanks! All three are bad options for me :) but I guess there is no good option. I expected some flag for the `print` statement (similar to the final `,`), but I see there is no way of telling print "do not put a space".

Comment: @gonvaled: That's one of the reasons Python 3 switched to a `print()` function; allowing you to actually alter the defaults. The `from __future__` import was added to help the transition from 2 to 3.

Answer (score 2):

Get used to use `print()` function instead of the statement. It's more flexible.

```
from __future__ import print_function

print('foo', end='')
print('bar')
```

Comment: This does mean that any module importing that for this case would require all `print` statements to be amended though